# How to properly reload tableview after saving new data to Parse?

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I updated my swift project and mistakenly deleted a function in my app. My `tableview` no longer reloads data immediately after it is uploaded to Parse. It only reloads when I close my app, and reopen it.

Before, after I would upload data, it would reload immediately after a performed segue.

Here is my `tableView` code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refreshTable", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        self.homeTimelineTableView.addSubview(refreshControl)


        self.refreshControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()


        homeTimelineTableView.delegate = self;
        homeTimelineTableView.dataSource = self;



        var query = PFQuery(className: "Product")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (products: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                // success fetching objects    
                for product in products! {

                    self.imagePNG.append(product["imagePNG"] as! PFFile)
                    self.shortDescription.append(product["shortDescription"] as! String)
                    self.productTitles.append(product["title"] as! String)
                    self.productPrice.append(product["price"] as! String)
                    self.productLongD.append(product["longDescription"] as! String)

                }

                // reload the timeline table
                self.homeTimelineTableView.reloadData()

            }else {

                println(error)
            }
        }

    }
```

Not sure what I am missing. I have tried adding `self.homeTimelineTableview.reloadData()` at the top of my `viewDidLoad`, assuming that would tell the `tableView` to reload once the controller opens, but that doesn't work.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: have to checked your query is returning data

Comment: Yes, the existing data is being returned. New data, however, I have to restart the app.

Answer (score 0):

Reload your `homeTimelineTableView` from main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.homeTimelineTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Yes he is correct. Any UI update should be executed on The main thread. Blocks are executed on separate thread. As a rule of thumb any UI updates shall be enclosed within dispatch_async if it is called from a block.

Comment: I've tried this, but it does not seem to work either.

Comment: Are you sure your array of tableview is updating?